# Why isn't my breadth first search algorithm working correctly to solve the ladder problem?

Tags: java, breadth-first-search

I am taking an algorithms and data structures class and I am working on an assignment where I have to use a breadth first search algorithm to solve the word ladder problem. It's not working and I'm not sure why. For some words it will be correct for the first few and then just start using words that are not one letter apart.

Code:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.*;

public class SENG300_Assignment13 {
    
    
    static Graph graph = new Graph();
    
    public static List<Vertex> adjustedBFS(Graph graph, Vertex startVertex, Vertex endVertex) {
        
          HashSet<Vertex> discoveredSet = new HashSet<Vertex>();
          Queue<Vertex> frontierQueue = new LinkedList<Vertex>();
          ArrayList<Vertex> visitedList = new ArrayList<Vertex>();
        
          // startVertex has a distance of 0 from itself
          //distances.put(startVertex, 0.0);
    
          frontierQueue.add(startVertex); // Enqueue startVertex in frontierQueue
          discoveredSet.add(startVertex); // Add startVertex to discoveredSet
          
          while (frontierQueue.size() > 0) {
              
             Vertex currentVertex = frontierQueue.remove();
             visitedList.add(currentVertex);
             
              if (currentVertex.equals(endVertex)) {
                  break;
              }
             
             for (Edge edge : graph.getEdgesFrom(currentVertex)) {
                Vertex adjacentVertex = edge.toVertex;
                
                if (!discoveredSet.contains(adjacentVertex)) {
                   frontierQueue.add(adjacentVertex);
                   discoveredSet.add(adjacentVertex);
                    
                   // Distance of adjacentVertex is 1 more than currentVertex
                   //distances.put(adjacentVertex, distances.get(currentVertex) + 1);
                }
             }
          }
          return visitedList;
       }
    
    public static void addEdgeForOneLetterApart(Graph graph) {
        List<Vertex> vertices = new ArrayList<>(graph.getVertices());
        
        for (int i = 0; i < vertices.size(); i++) {
            Vertex v1 = vertices.get(i);
            
            for (int j = 0; j < vertices.size(); j++) {
                Vertex v2 = vertices.get(j);
                
                if (areOneLetterApart(v1.getValue(), v2.getValue())) {
                    graph.addUndirectedEdge(v1, v2);
                    graph.addUndirectedEdge(v2, v1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    public static boolean areOneLetterApart(String v1, String v2) {
        int differenceCount = 0;
        
        if (v1.length() != v2.length()) {
            return false;
        }
        
        for (int i = 0; i < v1.length(); i++) {
            if (v1.charAt(i) != v2.charAt(i)) {
                differenceCount++;
                
                if (differenceCount > 1) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        
        return differenceCount == 1;
        
    }
    
    

    // Driver code
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Graph wordGraph = new Graph();
        FileInputStream fileByteStream = null;
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner inFS = null;
        String word;
        int counter = 0;
        
        
        try {
            fileByteStream = new FileInputStream("words_alpha.txt");
            inFS = new Scanner(fileByteStream);
            
            while (inFS.hasNextLine()) {
                word = inFS.nextLine();
                
                graph.addVertex(word);
                
                counter++;
                
            }
            
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        
        
        Vertex start = new Vertex("wing");
        Vertex target = new Vertex("left");
        
        addEdgeForOneLetterApart(graph);
        
        System.out.println(adjustedBFS(graph, start, target));
    }
}
```

And here is the output list when using those start and target variables:
[wing, wind, wine, ring, kind, mind, line, wire, wise, mine, wide, like, fire, side, size]

I'm really not sure what is going on, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: When you use a debugger, what is the *first* thing it does that you did not expect?

Comment: The name `addUndirectedEdge` suggests that this will add an **undirected** edge. Then why do you call it twice with the arguments exchanged?

Comment: @trincot calling it once does not seem to change the output.

Comment: I know, but it was a question.

Answer (score 2):

The main issue is that `visitedList` is populated in breadth-first order, so in general it will not represent a *path*. It contains all *visited* nodes, which of course have no guarantee to all be on the shortest path.

In your example graph, the starting node "wing" has as immediate neighbors "ring", "wind" and "wine", and these nodes will be visited before any other nodes, because that is what breadth first does. We can immediately see how these nodes will end up in `visitedList`, but also that they don't form a *path*. If there is a solution, it could be that only one of those three "siblings" will turn out to be on the path, but at the moment you visit them, you cannot know that yet. Only when the target node has been visited, you can reconstruct the path.

In order to do that, you need to remember for each node where you came from when you visited it. That will be information you can use to reconstruct the path once you have found the target node. From there you can follow those backreferences back to the starting node and reconstruct the path as you do that.

Some other remarks:

- Don't use a static `graph` field. You created `wordGraph` locally, which is good, but then you never use it, and use the static field instead. Drop the static field and only work with the local instance.
- You cannot print an ArrayList just by giving it as argument to `System.out.println`. Instead iterate the list and print the individual vertices.
- As the name `addUndirectedEdge` suggests that this method will create an **undirected** edge, it should not be necessary to call it twice -- which you would do if it would create a **directed** edge. But this depends on the actual implementation of that method. As you have not provided it, please check whether you need to call it twice or once.
- Related to the previous point: as in `addEdgeForOneLetterApart` you look at all neighbors of all nodes, you'll anyhow visit the same pair of nodes in the two possible orders, and call `graph.addUndirectedEdge` on both. So you could even limit the inner loop to avoid that "double" call, and have it start with `for (int j = i + 1; ...`

Here is a corrected version of `adjustedBFS`:

```
    public static List<Vertex> adjustedBFS(Graph graph, Vertex startVertex, Vertex endVertex) {
        // When discovering a node, track where we came from. Use a Map instead of Set:
        HashMap<Vertex, Vertex> discoveredLink = new HashMap<Vertex, Vertex>(); 
        Queue<Vertex> frontierQueue = new LinkedList<Vertex>();
        ArrayList<Vertex> visitedList = new ArrayList<Vertex>();
        
        frontierQueue.add(startVertex);
        discoveredLink.put(startVertex, null); // Start-vertex has no predecessor 
        
        while (frontierQueue.size() > 0) {
            Vertex currentVertex = frontierQueue.remove();
            // We don't know if this vertex will be on the path,
            //    so don't add it to visitedList yet
            if (currentVertex.equals(endVertex)) {
                // Reconstruct the path
                while (currentVertex != null) {
                    visitedList.add(currentVertex);
                    currentVertex = discoveredLink.get(currentVertex);
                }
                // As we started from the end vertex, we need to reverse:
                Collections.reverse(visitedList);
                break;
            }
            for (Edge edge : graph.getEdgesFrom(currentVertex)) {
                Vertex adjacentVertex = edge.toVertex;

                if (!discoveredLink.containsKey(adjacentVertex)) {
                    frontierQueue.add(adjacentVertex);
                    discoveredLink.put(adjacentVertex, currentVertex); // remember predecessor
                }
            }
        }
        return visitedList;
    }
```

The example you have given should return an empty list, as "left" is not a node in the graph. You could even make that a check in your program to avoid a useless BFS search. This is the visual representation of the example:

[image]

Answer (score -2):

```
function ladderLength(beginWord, endWord, wordList) {
if (!wordList.includes(endWord)) {
    return 0;
}

let queue = [[beginWord, 1]];
let visited = new Set([beginWord]);

while (queue.length > 0) {
    let [word, depth] = queue.shift();
    
    if (word === endWord) {
        return depth;
    }
    
    for (let i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
        let newWord = '';
        
        for (let j = 0; j < word.length; j++) {
            newWord += (j === i) ? '_' : word[j];
        }
        
        for (let c = 97; c <= 122; c++) {
            let nextWord = newWord.replace('_', String.fromCharCode(c));
            
            if (wordList.includes(nextWord) && !visited.has(nextWord)) {
                visited.add(nextWord);
                queue.push([nextWord, depth + 1]);
            }
        }
    }
}

return 0;
```

}

Comment: Consider adding some extra information, explain the code, fix the formatting, and tell what you changed in the code, to make it a proper answer.